# Android hide keyboard

Tags: android

I am working on android Tab which has external keyboard. So I need to remove the android soft keyboard pop on my App. I tried so many ways to do it, none of it works for me because my Device is an Api-16 .

```
EditText edtView=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextConvertValue);
edtView.setInputType(0);
```

This code was work but it didn't shows the cursor .I tried these,

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN
);
```

and

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"/>
```

nothing works for me.

Is there any other way to do it ??

## Hide Android softKeyboard pop on Api 16 device

thanks in advance !!

Comment: is this being done? http://android.stackexchange.com/a/80999/57580

Comment: Create a ViewUtil.java class to show or hide keyboard. You can take a look at the following https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/6023531

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
editView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){
            editView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edtView.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            },1);

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: etId(R.id.auth_code)     what is 'etId' . Is it view.getId

Comment: sorry. that is my personal library code..swiching edtView. anyway problem solve?

Comment: ya its working. thankss !!  But Whats the logic behind using the edtView.postDelayed  ...  can you elaborate plz  _

Comment: i got the point.here the keyboard is popping up after hide after 1ms.Anyway its a good solution..... thank you

Answer (score 1):

**call below function whenever you want to hide keyboard**

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Context context, View mView) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mView.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use These lines in xml code when use edittext and want to hide keyboard on focus/clicked.

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```