# How to avoid soft keyboard pushing up SINGLE VIEWS in my layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

If the soft keyboard comes up, it pushes up my layout - that is good. But I have a single `View` at the bottom of my layout, that I don't want to be pushed up. Is there a way, I can do this?

Thank you.

Comment: read this. i think it is help to you http://stackoverflow.com/a/41867144/4993283

Comment: i dont want to hide the keyboard - i want a certain view at the bottom of the layout not to be pushed up when the soft keyboard pops up

Answer (score 1):

You can use `KeyboardUtil` from this post:

[android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" doesn't make any difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398102/androidwindowsoftinputmode-adjustresize-doesnt-make-any-difference/30019136#30019136)

And translate this View to proper position every time keyboard is open / closed.